# Composition of logarithm, quadratic and $\tan$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, trigonometry

$f(x)=\ln(\tan{x}+2)+\ln(\tan{x}+3)=\ln(\tan^2{x}+5\tan{x}+6)$

Is $f(x)$ injective on $\langle3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle$? If so, find its inverse on that interval.

$\tan^2{x}+5\tan{x}+6>0\implies \tan{x}\in\langle-\infty,-3\rangle\cup\langle-2,+\infty\rangle$

$\mathcal D_f=x\in[2k\pi,2(k+1)\pi]\setminus\langle \arctan{(-3)+(2k+1)\pi,\arctan{(-2)}+(2k+1)\pi\rangle}$

$g_1(x)=\ln{x}$

$g_2(x)=x^2+5x+6$

$g_3(x)=\tan{x}$

$f(x)=(g_1\circ g_2 \circ g_3)(x)$

$g_3(x)$ is injective on $\langle3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle$ because the distance is less than a period.

$g_3(\langle3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle)=\langle0,+\infty\rangle$

$g_2(x)=x^2+5x+6$ is injective on $\langle0,+\infty\rangle$ because the $x$ coordinate of the vertex is $x_0=-\frac{5}{2}$

$g_2(\langle 0,+\infty\rangle)=\langle 6,+\infty\rangle$

$g_1(x)=\ln{x}$ is always injective.

$g_1(\langle6,+\infty\rangle)=\langle \ln6,+\infty\rangle$

$f_{|\langle3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle}^{-1}(w)=(g_{3|\langle 3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle}^{-1}\circ g_{2|\langle0,+\infty\rangle}^{-1}\circ g_{1}^{-1})(w)$
$=g_{3|\langle 3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle}^{-1}(g_{2|\langle0,+\infty\rangle}^{-1}(e^w))$

$z^2-5z+6-e^w=0\implies z=\frac{-5 +\sqrt{25+4(e^w-6)}}{2}=\frac{-5 +\sqrt{1+4e^w}}{2}$

$f_{|\langle3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle}^{-1}(w)=\Bigg(g_{3|\langle 3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\rangle}^{-1}\Bigg(\frac{-5 +\sqrt{1+4e^w}}{2}\Bigg)\Bigg)(w)=\arctan{\Bigg(\frac{-5 +\sqrt{1+4e^w}}{2}\Bigg)}$

Is this correct?

[[image: <span class=]$D_f$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmUSf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\in \left(3\pi,\frac{7\pi}{2}\right)$ we have $\tan x\in(0,\infty)$ and $\tan^2{x}+5\tan{x}+6$ is strictly increasing therefore $f(x)$ is injective with range $(\log 6, \infty)$.

To find the inverse we need to solve

$$y=\ln(\tan^2{x}+5\tan{x}+6) \iff \tan^2{x}+5\tan{x}+6-e^y=0$$

$$\tan x=\frac{-5+ \sqrt{1+4e^y}}{2} \implies x=\arctan\left(\frac{-5+ \sqrt{1+4e^y}}{2}\right)\color{red}{+3\pi}$$

Comment: Thanks, I see I wrote 2 instead of 6.

Comment: Moreover we need to add a $3\pi$ term at the end. You are welcome! Bye